# faster selection of multiple option values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a multi-select list-box with 100+ <option>

Now I have 7 or 8 values that needs to be selected.

My code is:

```
            var selObj = document.getElementById('list1');
            var len = selObj.length;
            var selected_values = '1#2#15#34#82#96';
            var selected_values_array = selected_values.split('#');
            var alen = selected_values_array.length;

            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < alen; j++) {
                    if (selObj[i].value == selected_values_array[j]) {
                        selObj[i].selected = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

When script is encountered, browser stops responding. I know my code is bad, but is their any way to improve it. Either using jQuery or javascript?

Thanks

Comment: You seem to have a bug in `for (j = 0; i < alen; j++)`. Shouldn't that be `j < alen`?

Comment: I have changed the following, but still the issue persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this with a little help of jQuery (got it working now):

```
var selected_values = '1#2#15#34#82#96';
var selectors = '#list1 > option[value="' + selected_values.split('#').join('"], #list1 > option[value="') + '"]';
$( selectors ).each( function() {
    $( this ).attr( 'selected', true );
} );
```

A bit uglier than I'd hoped. But hey. :)

See it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VHeca/). And [here is an edited version](http://jsfiddle.net/VHeca/1/) with a larger sized select box.

Comment: @I-M-JM: Yeah sorry about that, let me tweak it a bit more. Give me just a few more minutes. I'm looking for a way to select elements by multiple attributes at once. And I have a typo. :)

Comment: @I-M-JM: I got it working now. I was hoping I could select for multiple possible attribute values at once. But I had to string the complete selectors together unfortunately. Maby somebody else know how to make the concatenated selector string cleaner than this.

Comment: @I-M-JM: Alright, you're welcome. Was a nice short puzzle. :) Good luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$('#list1 option').each(function(i) {   

  for (j = 0; j < alen; j++) {
   if($(this).val() == selected_values_array[j]) {
     $(this).attr("selected", true);   
   }
  }
 });
```